# Настройка файла .htaccess

Tags: html, веб-программирование, .htaccess, apache

У меня на домене несколько страниц одного сайта (меню, акции и т.д). В адресной строке после домена идут их названия, но с расширением .html. Можно как-то убрать расширение или вообще убрать названия/ заменить их?

Comment: Не стоит это делать через .htaccess. Возьмите любой фреймворк с единой точкой входа.

Answer (score 0):

Через `.htaccess` это делается так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Включаем перезапись
  RewriteEngine On

  #
  # Секция, где можно переопределить URL на файлы в системе
  #

  # При запросе "/файла-нет,но-в-браузере-покажется-page.html" будет открыт page.html
  RewriteRule ^файла-нет,но-в-браузере-покажется-page.html$ page.html

  # При запросе /my-test-page также откроется page.html
  RewriteRule ^my-test-page$ page.html

  #
  # Секция, где добавляется .html
  #

  # Проверка: если файла нет,
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # но есть файл.html (если убрать это правило, то для несуществующих файлов будет 500 Internal Server Error)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  # то добавляем расширение .html
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```